# .NET Zip Libraries

Tags: c#, compression, zip

I'm currently looking for a .NET compression (zip) library. Due to our company's policies the library has to be a commercial one. That means that all the popular stuff (like DotNetZip) is out of question.

The only thing I came across is the Xceed library. Are there any alternatives?

PS: .NET 4.5 isn't an option right now since our products are still running on 4.0.

Comment: Nice policy. Could you tell us the name of your company? Sounds like a gold mine :-)

Comment: If you can use .NET 4.5, you do not need any library - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(VS.110).aspx.

Comment: Well, I think the idea behind that is that our company wants to be on the safe side when legal issues with used technology arise. Also we need to have some sort of support. (Of course I would love to use DotNetZip, but what can I do?....)

Comment: That is one outdated policy... wouldn't be surprised if they have a policy that limits them to .NET 1.0 only....

Comment: @NikolaAnusev: don't prevent people for spending their money. :)

Comment: @Boris we feel your pain, you have to stay away from GPL but perhaps there are libraries that use a much less restrictive license? In fact, your company probably has nothing to worry about the DotNetZip license: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/license, I would run it by the legal department... Because I expect the quality of open source effors like SharpZipLib or DotNetZip to be a lot higher than something made by a small one man company that offers commercial support. Not sure if you understand what I mean

Comment: you're asking for technical advice but it sounds like your company needs some quality legal advice first...

Comment: Thanks, Timothy. I'll make another attempt in suggesting DotNetZip ;-) If that fails I'll have to go for Xceed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not finding any reasonable commercial Zip Libraries, we ended up writing our own. Actually it wasn't a lot of work due to System.IO.Packaging.Package found in .NET 4.0 (no .NET 4.5 needed).

So if you can't use DotNetZip (due to the open source problem) and don't want to spend too much money this is a good third option.